# Javascript and PHP. Sending Multiple Array to PHP Using Ajax and Convert it to PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php

I need some help. I am trying to send multiply array of width and length to php, straight forward. I don't want to save it to any HTML field, however it's not working. I am getting the width and length from html text are and convert it to a number and then add it to an array in javascript.

Here is the code for that

```
var widthL = [];
var lengthL = [];

var widths = document.wall.width.value;
var lengths = document.wall.length.value;

var wNumber = Number(widths);
var lNumber = Number(lengths);

widthL.push(JSON.stringify(wNumber));
lengthL.push(JSON.stringify(lNumber));
```

This is the Ajax code I am using to send it to PHP

```
$.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "./Summary.php",
        data: {"widths": widthL, "lengths" : lengthL},
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("This is the width", widthL, " This is the length", lengthL);
        }

    });
```

In PHP I am using this code to receive it. But I am not getting things back.

```
<?php

$lengths = json_decode($_POST['lengths']);
$widths = json_decode($_POST['widths']);

echo 'This is the width: '.$widtsL;
echo 'This is the length: '.$lengths;
?>
```

I was hopping that someone could help me out here.

Comment: what do you get if you `var_dump($_POST[]);` ?

Comment: Dont `JSON.stringify()` stuff before you make the AJAX call. That will look after all of that for you if you add `dataType: "json"` to the ajax call

Comment: Add `dataType: "json"` to your `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: When I use var_dump($_POST['lengths']). I get NULL

Comment: try `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));`

Comment: I just $widths = var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));. And echo out $widths, I got nothing back.

Answer (score 0):

First you should specify the content type in the ajax POST:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "./Summary.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", // Add content type
    data: {"widths": widthL, "lengths" : lengthL},
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("This is the width", widthL, " This is the length", lengthL);
    }

});
```

then in PHP:

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); //This reads the raw POST data
$json = json_decode($request_body); // Then parse it to JSON
$lengths = $json->lengths;
$widths = $json->widths;
```

Comment: I have try you code and echo it out, still i am getting nothing back

Answer (score 0):

please add a POST parameter name as dataType，type it value JSON,
the Ajax data param value use key=value&key=value format 
then in php file enter debug code